# how to read the content of an incoming message from a specific phone number

Tags: android

I want to read the content of my incoming messages from a specific contact

This is the code that I have written for fetching the incoming messages.

```
public void doRead ( View v){
 ListView listitem=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Uri mSmsQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(mSmsQueryUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            // Log.i(TAG, "cursor is null. uri: " + mSmsQueryUri);

        }
        for (boolean hasData = cursor.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = cursor.moveToNext()) {
            final String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            final String sender_no = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
            final String date= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
            final String type =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));


            messages.add(body);
            messages.add(sender_no);
            messages.add(date);
            messages.add(type);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    listitem.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Reader.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,messages));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your query to filter by phone number

```
String[] phNumber = new String[] { "+000000000000" }; //phone number

    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), new String[] { "_id", "address","date","body", "type" }, "address=?", phNumber, null);
```